# Bs4 web scraper not providing actual link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to scrape 2lib.org for a download link, but for some reason the links being printed are not the links displayed when I manually go inspect them. Here's my code -

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://2lib.org/book/1844071/8add88/'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
for tag in soup.select('a.btn-primary.dlButton.addDownloadedBook'):
  print (f"2lib.org{tag['href']}")
```

Right now, it prints a link ending with 4da009, which is not the link I get when I go manually inspect the site. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify `User-Agent`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://2lib.org/book/1844071/8add88/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

for tag in soup.select("a.btn-primary.dlButton.addDownloadedBook"):
    print(f"https://2lib.org{tag['href']}")
```

Prints:

```
https://2lib.org/dl/1844071/e50b5e
```

Comment: Nope, still results in a ?wrongHash on the url

Comment: @JohnDuck You don't get the `e50b5e` in the URL?

Comment: Nah, just realized that it's dependant on your IP, so different for everyone. Thanks tho man.